# Pagestyle empty and plain. Other ones?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

my problem is that I want to empty the footer but not the header.
`\thispagestyle{empty}` empties both of them.
`\thispagestyle{plain}` empties only the header, but not the footer.

Is there a third command to empty the footer, but not the header?

I just want to skip a numbering of a page in my document. Something like:
page 1, page 2, page 3, page, page 4, page 5.
There ist a page between 3 and 4, but it is not counted.
My idea was to empty the footer and use `\setcounter{page}{4}` at the next page.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Maybe it is possible to use \thispagestyle{empty}, but also to let the heading (my name) appear again?

Comment: the fancyhdr package makes it very easy to declare any number of page styles doing whatever you want

Comment: The problem is, that I can't use \thispagestyle{headings} or \thispagestyle{myheadings} because I used \fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{\small \scshape myname}. If I use the above commands, I get ,,Contents'' in the heading and not my name

Comment: That's my problem :D How to define such a pagestyle where header appears, but footer disappears?

Comment: I take it you are using a oneside document class, as adding an uncounted page would mess up odd/even tests.  I believe hypreref uses a separate page counter, so that the PDF can find unnumbered or duplicate pages.

Comment: BTW, you need to use \pagestyle{fancy} with fancyhdr.  The other pagestyles are unchanged and still available.  Interestingly, \fancypagestyle performs formatting changes and uses \pagestyle{fancy}.

Comment: For a single page, one can use tikzpagenodes and (current page header area).

Comment: Hey, yes one sided document. I found a solution to my numbering problem using
\pagenumbering{gobble}. But I would like to know if there is a command to let the footer disappear, but not the header :)

Comment: The short answer is no. But you can create a new pagestyle using the current header (assuming you know what it is) and no footer.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Hey, could you please explain how to create a new pagestyle. I can't find any sources for that. And to be sure: I want to use this pagestyle only for ONE page, not for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two examples, one using fancyhdr and one without. There is also `\fancypagestyle` which is described in the fancyhdr manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyhead[C]{\small \scshape myname}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@ugly{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty
    \def\@oddhead{\hfill\small \scshape myname\hfill}%
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}% default

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]% first page no header
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[9-14]% second page fancy
\thispagestyle{ugly}
\lipsum[15-21]% third page ugly, fourth page default
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Could you please explain the part between \fancyhead[C]... and \begin{document}? And could I replace \def by \newcommand?

Comment: If you look in artcile.cls (base folder) you will find definitions for \ps@empty, \ps@plain, \ps@headings and \ps@myheadings.  You could use \newcommand{ps@ungly}{...} since \ps@ungly was not previously defined, but you should use \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{...} since it IS defined already.  I used \def since that is how article.cls did it, and because I don't really care whether they were previously defined or not.